# powershell script to download updates

Tags: powershell

I had written a PowerShell script to download and install windows updates as follows. This script will run powershell to run as administrator. I run on a windows 7 computer but it keep having a loop of opening the powershell windows. pls advise

```
enter code here

If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]   
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole   
([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
```

```
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
 Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments




  #define type of updates

   $criteria="Isinstalled=0 and Type='driver'"

  #Search for relevant updates


     $Searcher=New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Searcher
      $SearchResult=$Searcher.Search($criteria).updates

       if($SearchResult.Count -gt 0) { 


       $Session=New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
      $Downloader=$Session.CreateUpdateDownloader()
   $Downloader.Updates=$SearchResult
   $Downloader.Download()

   $installer=New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Installer
   $installer.Updates=$SearchResult
   $Install_Begin=$installer.Install()

     }

  break

  }
```

Comment: If you open it in ISE you'll see the problem, the type decorators in your if statement are not formatted properly.  I'm guessing you just need to remove `[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]` but I didn't test

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, if you are trying to install updates from PowerShell you can do this from two easy lines of code.

The first would be to install the module for updates and the second would be to run the updates.

Please see the code below for updating windows.

```
install-module pswindowsupdate
Install-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
```